# warning showing file name and line number of routine returning outdated return format

Tags: python, plugins, warnings

When I have created a library in which a function or method will be deprecated, I can warn users
of the library of the fact using `warnings.warn(message, PendingDeprecationsWarning)`. By setting the `stacklevel` parameter for `warnings.warn`
appropriately, I can have the warning refer to where the to-be-deprecated function was called from, which is way more informative to the user of the library.

But I have a plugin based system that calls the `.status` method of a user supplied plug-in class.
The status method used to return a `dict`, but that is going to be deprecated
in favour of returning a `list` (this is a simplification of the actual situation).
In this case the warning is not useful to the user providing the plug-in:

```py
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('once', PendingDeprecationWarning)


class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.plug_ins = []

    def load_plug_ins(self):
        sys.path.append('plug_ins')
        for file_name in Path('plug_ins').glob('p*.py'):
            mod = import_module(file_name.stem) 
            self.plug_ins.append(mod.PlugIn())

    def check_status(self):
        for p in self.plug_ins:
            retval = p.status()
            if isinstance(retval, dict):
                # assume dict
                warnings.warn('status() should return list, not dict', PendingDeprecationWarning)
            else:
                pass  # assume list

# create some plug-ins
Path('plug_ins/p0.py').write_text("""\
class PlugIn:
    def status(self):
        return {'result': 'ok'}
""")
Path('plug_ins/p1.py').write_text("""\
class PlugIn:
    def status(self):
        return ['ok'] # this plug-in has been updated
""")
Path('plug_ins/p2.py').write_text("""\
class PlugIn:
    def status(self):
        return {'result': 'ok'}
""")


driver = Driver()
driver.load_plug_ins()
for idx in range(2):
    driver.check_status()
```

which gives:

```
/tmp/ryd-115/tmp_00.py:23: PendingDeprecationWarning: status() should return list, not dict
  warnings.warn('status() should return list, not dict', PendingDeprecationWarning)
```

The path and the line number in the output is that from the file with the Driver class defined.
What I want to be shown is the actual paths to the files defining `status`, and that methods line-number, and that once for each file (`p0.py` and `p2.py`) that needs updating.

How can I use the normal Python warning system (so I can tell the users to use the normal
warning filtering to suppress messages) and show the filename and line of the `status` method
that needs to be updated, instead of showing the file-name and line where that warning is in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify `warnings.formatwarning` for the warning that
you invoke, so you need to define a warning to pass to `warnings.warn`.
If you create more of these warnings having a warning subclass, where all the others are derived from, makes sense.

That a message is printed once, requires it to be hashable, and
instead of a string as first parameter to `warnings.warn` you can
provide a tuple (that you then unpack in `formatwarning`):

```py
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module
import warnings

class PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning(PendingDeprecationWarning):
    pass

# warn once on all PlugIn deprecations
warnings.simplefilter('once', PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning)

warnings.org_formatwarning = warnings.formatwarning
def my_formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line):
    if isinstance(message, PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning):
        try:
            message, filename, lineno = message.args[0]
        except Exception as e:  # in case there was no tuple provided
            pass
    return warnings.org_formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line)
warnings.formatwarning = my_formatwarning


class DictReturnPendingDeprecationWarning(PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning):
    pass

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.plug_ins = []

    def load_plug_ins(self):
        sys.path.append('plug_ins')
        for file_name in Path('plug_ins').glob('p*.py'):
            mod = import_module(file_name.stem) 
            self.plug_ins.append(mod.PlugIn())

    def check_status(self):
        for p in self.plug_ins:
            retval = p.status()
            if isinstance(retval, dict):
                # assume dict
                code = p.status.__func__.__code__
                warnings.warn(
                   ('callable should return list, not dict', code.co_filename, code.co_firstlineno),
                   DictReturnPendingDeprecationWarning,
                )
            else:
                pass  # assume list

driver = Driver()
driver.load_plug_ins()
for idx in range(2):
    driver.check_status()
```

which gives:

```
/Users/anthon/src/se/so_q_000/plug_ins/p0.py:2: DictReturnPendingDeprecationWarning: callable should return list, not dict
  def status(self):
/Users/anthon/src/se/so_q_000/plug_ins/p2.py:2: DictReturnPendingDeprecationWarning: callable should return list, not dict
  def status(self):
```

You should be able to import the `PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning` (probably have it defined in a seperate file
and import it in your Driver code),
and then let your users do:

```
import warnings
from somefile import PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', PlugInPendingDeprecationWarning)
```

in their plug-in, but it will of course affect all other plug-ins as well.

You can also install [`ruamel.std.warnings`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.std.warnings/) from PyPI and let it extend the `warnings.warn()` function with an optional `callee` parameter:

```python
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module
import ruamel.std.warnings
import warnings

class DictReturnPendingDeprecationWarning(PendingDeprecationWarning):
    pass

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.plug_ins = []

    def load_plug_ins(self):
        sys.path.append('plug_ins')
        for file_name in Path('plug_ins').glob('p*.py'):
            mod = import_module(file_name.stem)
            self.plug_ins.append(mod.PlugIn())

    def check_status(self):
        for p in self.plug_ins:
            retval = p.status()
            if isinstance(retval, dict):
                # assume dict
                warnings.warn(
                   'callable should return list, not dict',
                   DictReturnPendingDeprecationWarning,
                   callee=p.status,
                )
            else:
                pass  # assume list

warnings.simplefilter('once', PendingDeprecationWarning)

driver = Driver()
driver.load_plug_ins()
for idx in range(2):
    driver.check_status()
```

with the same effect.